# Receiving error; AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app' while using render_template in return statement

Tags: python, html, flask, rendering

I am trying to display the plotted figure using the web browser. But the render template in return statement is throwing error. Below is the code used and the error received.

The python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder = 'D:/DATA_SETS')

@app.route('/html_example')
def myplot():
    with app.app_context():
        plt.figure()
        t = range(0,6,1)
        x= np.sin(t)
        plt.plot(t,x)
        plt.savefig('D:/DATA_SETS/new_plot.png')
        return Response(render_template('template_1.html', name = 'new_plot', url ='D:/DATA_SETS/new_plot.png'))

f = myplot()

if 1 == 1:
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The template template_1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Performance</h1>

        <p>{{ name }}</p>

        <img src={{ url}} alt="Chart" height="42" width="42">

   </body>
</html>
```

Expected : The image return from function should be displayed in the HTML format written.

Current : The webpage is displaying 'Not Found Error'.
Webpage looking at is 'http://localhost:5000/html_example'

Comment: Are you sure that the port is 5000 and the template template_1.html is inside templates folder ?

Comment: I am running the code from Spyder, an it is not displaying any port details.And I saved template in a different folder 'D:/DATA_SETS', so mentioned same in Flask().

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the port, i gave custom port and the template is displayed. now getting a new problem. the image is not opening. code edited:  app.run(debug=True,host='localhost', port=9874)

Comment: Please check if the image is created and already inside D:/DATA_SETS/.

Comment: its created and is available in the folder.

Comment: does src="{{ url}}" fix the problem. if not please inspect img and check if the url is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the return statement. It should be

```
return render_template('template_1.html', name = 'new_plot', url ='D:/DATA_SETS/new_plot.png'))
```

and you should not be doing

```
f= myplot()
```

for producing the image.
when you will hit the URL `localhost:5000/` it will automatically do the process of producing image and serve it to frontend.

Update:
Directory Structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path="/folder/",static_folder="folder")

@app.route('/')
def myplot():
        plt.figure()
        t = range(0,6,1)
        x= np.sin(t)
        plt.plot(t,x)
        plt.savefig(app.static_folder+'/'+'new_plot.png')
        return render_template('template_1.html', name = 'new_plot', filename ='new_plot.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

template_1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Performance</h1>

        <p>{{ name }}</p>

        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=filename) }}" alt="Chart" height="100" width="100">

   </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for the response. but wrapping code into app_context function worked. Now  I am facing a new issue.  I am not able to view output.

Comment: @ShanmukhaReddy the template was not rendering because `flask` by default checks for templates you ask to render in template directory of root folder and you might be keeping the `template_1.html` in root folder. I Have updated my answer with few corrections

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your code into with app.app_context function. Your code will be similar to this:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder = 'templates')

@app.route('/')
def myplot():
    with app.app_context():
       plt.figure()
       t = range(0,6,1)
       x= np.sin(t)
       plt.plot(t,x)
       plt.savefig('D:/DATA_SETS/new_plot.png')
       return Response(render_template('template_1.html', name = 'new_plot', 
       url ='D:/DATA_SETS/new_plot.png'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. but i am still unable to see the output in web-page.